# Use Case Diagram - Actors

Tags: documentation, uml, use-case

I need to create a Use Case diagram using the following scenario, this is all I have to work with so it should work according to this.

My Actors are - Buyer, Seller and User (I think)

**Scenario**

The eAuction system allows multiple users to conduct auctions electronically. Once a user has setup an account,
they are able to act as a seller and start an auction by listing an item to be sold. They may also act as a buyer by
browsing auctions that are in progress and bidding on any item whose auction has not closed. A user does not
need to setup an account to simply browse auctions in progress.

An auction is started when a seller inputs data including, a description of the item, the starting price, the reserve
price and a date when the auction will close. The system enforces an upper and lower bidding increment of 20%
and 10% of the starting price respectively. The system also enforces a closing date ≤ 7 days from the current date.
Once the data has been input, the auction automatically becomes pending and the seller must verify the auction
before it starts.

When a user wants to make a bid against an item, they must first locate the auction in question by browsing the
auctions that are in progress. They may then make a bid that the system must check is within the upper and lower
bidding increment amounts.
Each auction keeps track of every bid made against the item. Once the auction closes the system checks to see if
the item’s reserve price has been met and if so, informs the buyer with the highest bid of their victory. If the item’s
reserve price has not been met, the system informs every buyer who made a bid and the auction is closed.

Both sellers and auctions may be temporarily blocked which prevents the sellers from logging on or the auctions
from being browsed or bid upon respectively.

Comment: How about adding a few paragraphs to make this readable?

Comment: My apologies, can you work with this? Would it just be one actor for example the user

Comment: Himynameis, what your question is actually? We can see that you need to create a diagram and there is a process description, but no question you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. An actor represents a role someone or something plays with respect to the system under consideration (SUC). It does not matter on its physical representation. Anyone can act in any role towards the SUC. Restrictions, if any, can be expressed as constraints attached to the actors (e.g. `{ a Seller may not act as Buyer in the same UC}`).

There are quite a number of use cases. The first is `Setup account` which enables `Auctioneer` to start auctions. He has `List item for auction` as next UC. And `Buyer` has `Bid for listed item`. I'm not sure about closing the auction. Maybe, if like on ebay, this is done by a `Timer` actor which has `Close auction` be performed after a certain time. Also not sure about the blocking condition. This can be expresses as a constraint. But there might as well be a `Watcher` actor who blocks users according to a rule set. Just start by placing those UCs and the according actors on a UC diagram. Then start discussing with stakeholders about the completeness. You will eventually find more actors and UCs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm struggling with the use cases in this scenario are you able to help?

Comment: If you ask the correct way, I might be able. Please edit your question.

Comment: Hope it helps, I'm trying to figure out each case diagram

Comment: I tried to give you a start with the UCs. The work is still up to you to complete it.